# Google App Engine YAML resources configs not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, resources

I am deploying a NODE JS app on Google App Engine and for some reason my deployment is always a F1 instance (very low resources config).

My app.yaml is like this:

```
runtime: nodejs8
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 7.50
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are specify a configuration settings for App Engine Flexible - but it looks like you are running App Engine Standard. You should use `instance_class` for Standard. F1 also indicates Standard.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `instance_class`:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref

For example:

```
runtime: nodejs8
instance_class: F2
```